# Programatically assign a retina photo to a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

In the app the user takes a photo and then the photo is assigned to a button which they can tap to retake the photo. I'm having trouble getting it to work for a retina image.

Here's the code:

```
BodyData *lastPerson = (BodyData*)[ReadPerson readLastEntry];
CGRect frame = self.frontImage.frame;
CGSize doubleSize = CGSizeMake(self.frontImage.frame.size.width * 2, self.frontImage.frame.size.height * 2);

NSLog(@"frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frontImage.frame));

UIImage *frontPhoto = [[UIImage imageWithData:[lastPerson readPhotoOfSize:Full withAngle:Front withPlaceholderIfNoImage:NO]] resizeTo: doubleSize]; // Custom category to resize image

if (frontPhoto) {
    [[self.frontImage imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [self.frontImage setImage:frontPhoto forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.frontImage setImage:[frontPhoto darkenedImage] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.frontImage setFrame:frame];
    [self.frontImage.imageView setFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"frontimage sized to: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.frontImage.frame.size));
}
```

The log output is:

```
frame is: {{20, 145}, {129, 172}}
frontimage sized to: {258, 344}
```

Autolayout is enabled, but the images aren't changed at viewdidload, but rather on a notification that photos have been taken.

How do I get a retina quality image to be the value of the button? I've added all the frame resize stuff in because the button is being resized and I'm trying to override it, but even that doesn't work.

So the button should be: {129, 172} with an @2x version of the photo. But instead it's {258, 344} with an @1x version of the photo.

Comment: Not clear what isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to adjust the scale of the image:

```
UIImage *otherImage;
UIImage *image              = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:otherImage.CGImage
                                                         scale:otherImage.scale * 2.0f
                                                   orientation:otherImage.imageOrientation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Be clear with one thing. if u have a button with 10x10 pixel size, Then  you have to use 10x10 size image for non-retina display & 20x20 size image for retina display.

You said that photo is taken by user,and then set to button. In case to achieve retina quality you have to perform some scaling on image in order to set it as retina image.